# Union Error Message on Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an error message that says

> run-time error 1004': method 'union' of object'_Global' failed

and it is pointing to the line `Set unioned = Union(unioned, c)`
any tips?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub HideRows_Click()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'On Error Resume Next

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets

        Select Case ws.name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3" 'sheets to exclude
                'do nothing

            Case Else 'hide rows on these sheets
                Dim unioned As Range

                Dim c As Range
                For Each c In ws.Range("AJ16:AJ153,AJ157:AJ292")
                    If Len(c.Value2) = 0 Then
                        If unioned Is Nothing Then
                            Set unioned = c
                        Else
                            Set unioned = Union(unioned, c)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next c

                unioned.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select

    Next ws

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: do you know if it is on the first or second sheet loop?

Comment: I think you need to add `Set unioned = Nothing` after `unioned.EntireRow.Hidden = True`  as it is trying to create a unioned range of two different sheets which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks Scott. The error went away but unfortunately the code isn't doing what i want it to. the rows with 0's in column AJ are still present and not hidden. any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: are they in the second group or first group or both.  My guess is it works for the first group but not the second.

Comment: Is there a way to tell which group it is occurring in? None of the sheets have the hidden rows

Comment: `Len(c.Value2) = 0` is checking for no content, not for zeroes `If Len(c.Value2) > 0 And c.Value2 = 0` is maybe what you need